# What does this symbol mean in C++? "~"

Tags: c++

If we use `~` before a function like this: `~func();`, what does this mean?

Thanks.

Comment: Before an expression (that happens to call to a function), or before the declaration of a function (method)?

Comment: It *could* also be the one's complement of the returned value...

Comment: @Mehrdad: I suppose it could if it's a function call rather than a function declaration.

Comment: @Fred: It probably is, judging that a class called `func` is pretty rare. :)

Comment: @Fred: even in a function call this could be part of the function name, making this a destructor call. It all depends on what stands *before* the operator, or, if this is in a class, whether the function name coincides with a valid alias to the function name. Sounds complicated? Hell yeah!

Comment: It's just a cute little tail.

Comment: @Noah: Yeah; in math, `5!` is also just an excited `5`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it's part of a class definition, it's a destructor for that class, provided the function name is the same as the class name (Otherwise it would be a syntax error).

```
class stuff {
  stuff(); // constructor for stuff
  ~stuff(); // destructor for stuff
};
```

It could also be a bit-wise not operator. i.e.

```
int x = ~func();
```

In this context, it will take the return value from `func()`, which is presumably returning an integral type, flip all the bits and store the result in `x`.

If `func()` returns an object which has `operator~` defined in its class, then it could mean just about anything ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're referring to a function declaration, that indicates a `destructor` -- a function that is run automatically when an object is destroyed. Destructors are normally used to release any resources used by the object (free memory, close files, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

it specifies the destructor of a class or struct

Answer (score 2):

Its the Destructor. A function guarenteed to be called when the object is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

It's the bitwise complement operator.

(Actually, no, it's probably not a destructor. Destructor of a class named `func`??)

It takes the returned integer from `func()` and bitwise-complements it; that is, it flips all of its bits.

Comment: I don't attach too much significance to the name of the function; it could very well be replacing the name of a class, and the significance of that was not recognized by the poster.

Comment: Yes, "~func()" based on the sample I have would be a "Destructor", and you are right in naming, I may should have named it a more reasonable name to be thought as a Destructor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it is ~Foo, where Foo is a class, it is a destructor.

If it is used in other cases, it is the bitwise negation operator. It flips all the bits set to 1 to 0, and vice versa.